How is multi-sentence dialogue in prose punctuated when dialogue tags do not end the sentence?
Dialogue tags conventionally will be punctuated in a way that follows the structure of the dialogue itself:

"This is a sentence," Alice said. "This is another sentence."

But what is the rule for when the dialogue tags don't end the sentence?

A: "This is a sentence," Alice said, and then added, "This is another sentence."
B: "This is a sentence," Alice said, and then added, "this is another sentence."
C: "This is a sentence," Alice said, and then added. "This is another sentence."
D: None of these is grammatical.


Your version A is the correct form:

"This is a sentence," Alice said, and then added, "This is another sentence."

But commonly unnecessary dialogue tags are avoided and in most fiction today your example would read something like:

"This is a sentence," Alice said. "This is another sentence."

It is unmistakeably clear (because both utterances are given within the same paragraph with a paragraph break before and after it) that Alice says both sentences and thus "adds" the second to the first. Stating the obvious is both redundant and makes your writing feel cluttered.

Note that you wouldn't capitalize the second clause if it was a continuation of the first, e.g.:

"This is," Alice said, paused briefly, and then added, "a sentence."

Also, in this case stating that Aliced adds the second part of the sentence (after her pause might make her listeners assume that she has stopped speaking) is not redundant and makes the narrative flow more elegantly. Compare:

"This is," Alice said and paused briefly, "a sentence."


The example I gave was intended to be as distilled as possible to get to the heart of the question.  I agree that in 99.9% of cases, it would be bad writing to have multiple dialogue tags like that, but one can imagine a circumstance where it might be preferred, e.g.: "No, you're staying here," Alice said, and as Bob opened his mouth to protest, she added, "Didn't you promise Charlie you'd train with him today?"

@ArbitraryRenaissance Often, when I just answer the exact question, there is some need to clarify what OP meant and what I meant etc. So I tried to take into account the possibility that you need more information than just "A is correct", because I cannot read your mind. Also, I think that in this way my answer is more useful to others who might have a similar question and who do need the additional information. I believe this doesn't make my answer (that A is correct) less correct or less useful to you, and I don't understand why you need to criticise me for it.

It wasn't my intention to criticize your answer with the clarification I gave.  I only meant to give insight into why I would find this question interesting or worth asking.  That said, while your answer is good, I do find it a bit incomplete, because it doesn't explain why A is correct.  An explanation on how it would follow from established convention, or a citation of a commonly accepted style guide, would help.  I tried looking for an answer in the Chicago Manual, for instance, but I didn't get any conclusive answers there.

@ArbitraryRenaissance CMOS 6.20 explains the punctuation around and capitalization of dialogue. It doesn't contain your exact structure, but it provides an example for the relevant part of your example (You: '... Alice ... added, "This is ..." ' == CMOS: 'She replied, “I hope you aren’t referring to us.” '). The general rules are: (1) There is a comma between a dialogue tag and the dialogue, and (2) sentences begin with a capital letter.

@ArbitraryRenaissance You are probably confused because English uses commas to separate dialogue tags and dialogue, and one doesn't capitalize the first word after a comma. But if the quoted dialogue is a full sentence, one does.

The dissonance in the "correct" option for me stems from the fact that there are two sentences baked into the prose, but only one period.  It feels a bit as though omiting the period implies that there's a continuation of the first clause, e.g.: "You can," Alice said, "but that doesn't mean you should." in contrast to, "You can," Alice said. "That doesn't mean you should."  I do see how options B and C in the original question are inconsistent with CMOS though.

+1 Ben.
But for a frame challenge: You don't necessarily need dialogue tags at all!
You can craft the story story so the tag is implied. Meaning, it is either the character's natural turn to speak, or we imply the tag by having the character take some action that focuses the reader's attention on them.

Alice closed her eyes in frustration. "This is a sentence ... this is another sentence."
She opened her eyes and looked at David, imploring him. "Is that so hard?"

No dialogue tags, no "said", "whispered", "shouted", "screamed", "sobbed", whatever.
Although such tags do tend to disappear for readers, fiction is often better off without them. It is slightly more words to turn the reader's mental focus to a character about to speak, but often aids their visual imagination and can convey character emotion without describing the speech itself.
I think avoiding dialogue tags makes for a more immersive reader experience.

It's unclear to me who's saying "Is that so hard?" since while I would conventionally expect it to be David, it is Alice who is said to be doing the imploring there. So while the first paragraph is fine without tags, I would include them in the second or reword.

Really? "She" in the second sentence refers to the most recent female mentioned, "Alice". Alice is looking at David. The spoken words are on the same line. I don't think an attribution is necessary; but everybody is entitled to write as they wish.
